# pyplot figure will not open

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

using spyder from the IPython console, I can't get a figure to open a new window. I've copied below how the commands I used appear in the console window right after opening spyder. Instead of a new window opening with my scatter plot, the graph is shown in the console.

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [2]: plt.figure()
Out[2]: <matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xfdac6a0><matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xfdac6a0>

In [3]: plt.scatter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
Out[3]: <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x14fa7438>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *the graph is shown in the console*?

Comment: was going to update my post with a screen shot, but need reputation 10 to do that...
If I save this code to a script and run it from the command line, the figure does show up, but I'd rather be able to do this stuff in I python so I can look at the data ad hoc.

Answer (score 1):

You need write

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.scatter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
plt.show()
```

`show()` is the method to display the graph. The goal of the previous instruction is only set up pyplot object(figure).

Finally to show the figure in a new window you need to go to the tab `console`  and then to the tab `python`.

[image: Graphic]

Comment: If I enter your code, I get: http://pastebin.com/Ki82tKye ... and no window opens.

Comment: Sorry @TorstenBronger, but I don't know a solution for pastebin platform. This question is about Spyder then my answer is for Spyder platform only. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

A friend suggested I page through the preferences menu in spyder. there I found the option to change the "graphics backend" from Inline to Automatic. This solved my problem *after* I restarted spyder. Thanks for the suggestions though.